# How to remove the line breaks in front of a tag in Xpath

Tags: python, xpath

So here is my HTML code:

```
</div><div id="structureDescs" class="buttonWrap"><h2>Structure Descriptors</h2>
        <div><h3>InChI</h3>
            1S/C2H4O/c1-2-3/h2H,1H3<br>
            <button type="button" id="downloadInchi">Download</button>
        </div>


        <div><h3>InChIKey</h3>
            IKHGUXGNUITLKF-UHFFFAOYSA-N<br>
            <button type="button" id="googleInchi">Search the web for this InChIKey</button>
        </div>


        <div class="scrollWrapper"><h3>Smiles</h3>
            CC=O<br>
            <button type="button" id="downloadSmiles">Download</button>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Now I am trying to select the text "CC=O" right before the `<br>` tag in the Smiles section. I've done so in XPath and Python with `tree.xpath('//*[text()="Smiles"]/..//br[1]/preceding-sibling::text()[1]')`

However, my output is ['\n\t\t\tCC=O'] and I would like to get rid of the line breaks and tabs for my desired output of just "CC=O". Suggestions?

Comment: Only in front? Would removing those characters anywhere they existed in a result be acceptable? What about returning substrings separated by groups of those characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Python side, you could use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove whitespace from both sides of the string:

```
In [290]: data = ['\n\t\t\tCC=O']

In [291]: data[0].strip()
Out[291]: 'CC=O'
```

or, on the XPath side, you could use [`normalize-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space):

```
In [299]: tree.xpath('normalize-space(//*[text()="Smiles"]/..//br[1]/preceding-sibling::text())')
Out[299]: 'CC=O'
```

Note that in addition to removing both leading and trailing whitespace, `normalize-space` replaces multiple spaces with a single space.